# Preventing O(n) Queries with Intermediary Models

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def primary_group(self):
        return self.memberships.select_related('group').get(is_primary=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, related_name='memberships')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField()
```

`Artist` and `Group` are linked via an intermediary model, `Membership`. Artists can only have one primary group, which is marked via `is_primary`, validated, etc.

In a template where I list artists, I list basic artist information in addition to their primary group, called by the method above. However, that's an O(n) operation and I have around 160 artists to do this to. The SQL that the django-debug-toolbar provides is as follows:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "people_membership" 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN "people_group" ON ("people_membership"."group_id" = "people_group"."id") 
           WHERE ("people_membership"."artist_id" = xx AND "people_membership"."is_primary" = true )
```

Let me add that this happens for every artist listed, so I get about 160 of these.

Is O(n) the best that can be done, considering that I call a model method? Or is there something else I can do to improve this (short of denormalizing `primary_group`)? This seems to be a problem with any sort of information that is stored in an intermediary model that I'd like to call from either the source or the target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily do this with two queries, which despite what any haters will say, doesn't matter at all:

```
artists = list(Artist.objects.all())
primary_memberships = {m.artist_id: m for m in Group.objects.filter(is_primary=True, membership__artist__in=artists).extra(select={'artist_id': '%s.artist_id' % (Membership._meta.db_table,)})}
for artist in artists:
    artist.primary_membership = primary_memberships.get(artist.id)
```

(The extra clause may not be correct, but you get the idea)

In addition to this, I would change the primary function to do like:

```
if hasattr(self, '_primary_membership_cache'):
    return self._primary_membership_cache
```

And then if you attach the information, bind it to that variable, and just use your same function call.

(We follow this kind of pattern all over the place at DISQUS for various joins/odd queries)

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like David Cramer says but instead of extra:

```
primary_memberships = {m.artist_id: m.group for m in Membership.objects.filter(group__isprimary=True, artist__in=artists).select_related('group')}
for artist in artists:
    artists.primary_membership = primary_memberships.get(artist.id)
```

For bonus points make this a method on membership's manager so you can apply it to any list of artists easily!

Answer (score 1):

How about putting a two-column index on `membership`(`artist_id`, `is_primary`)?  [If you've already upgraded to 1.5b1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5805) you can do this within your models, but nothing's stopping you from doing this on the backend if you haven't.  That should reduce the membership lookup to constant time.  If your DB supports it, you can make it a [partial index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_index), but with only 160 artists, that doesn't seem all that necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting the query with the membership, rather than the Artist?

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    ...
    def primary_group(self):
        return Membership.objects.filter(artist=self).get(is_primary=True).group
```

Comment: The resulting query is about the same.